# Insert Price of main product to duplicate product list in MS Excel Using Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Hy Experts, I have a spreadsheet that consists of the product name and price list. But the product column contains many duplicates of the original product. This duplicate is separated by +1,+2----+30 values at the end of each product name. But the price column of these products contains the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQrCV.png)wrong price. The structure of the worksheet is as under.

This is an example of the product and price. The duplicate product has contained the wrong price. The should be like the original product. I am using this macro but it deletes the duplicate value entire row.

```
    Option Explicit

Sub DeleteDuplicateValues()
'
' DeleteDuplicateValues Macro
' Delete Duplicate Values with different Criteria
'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("A1:J1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*1+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

   Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*2+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*3+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*4+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*5+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*6+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*7+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*8+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*9+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*10+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*11+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*12+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*13+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*14+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*15+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*16+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*17+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*18+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*19+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*20+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*21+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*22+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*23+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*24+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$43000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*25+*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("4:4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    MsgBox ("Data Cleaning Succesfully")



End Sub
```

How it could be done that it should not delete the row. But it should enter the original price of product.

Thanks Advance..

Comment: Perhaps you could use Find ( *+) and Replace (nothing) to get rid of the extraneous text and then Find to find the correct formula.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of code could do the trick:

```
    Option Explicit


    Sub test()

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim STRcell As String

For i = 1 To LastRow

    If Right(Cells(i, 3).Value, 1) = "+" Then
        If Left(Right(Cells(i, 3).Value, 3), 1) = " " Then
            STRcell = Left(Cells(i, 3).Value, Len(Cells(i, 3).Value) - 3)
            Cells(i, 3).Offset(0, 4).Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(STRcell, Range("C:Z"), 5, 0) 'previously Findval(STRcell, Range("C:C"))

        ElseIf Left(Right(Cells(i, 3).Value, 4), 1) = " " Then
            STRcell = Left(Cells(i, 3).Value, Len(Cells(i, 3).Value) - 4)
            Cells(i, 3).Offset(0, 4).Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(STRcell, Range("C:Z"), 5, 0) 'previously Findval(STRcell, Range("C:C"))
        End If

    End If

Next


End Sub
```

The issue with this is if the format is different, for example if you don t have a space before the "5+" or if you have a 3digit number before the + (ex: "100+")

Comment: Any one can help me in this regard?

Comment: What is highlighted? the "Findval"?

Comment: Yes Findval is highlighted

Comment: And you also inserted the Function FINDval? (End of the code)

Comment: Yes it highlit FINDval as error 91  in function code area.

Comment: FINDval = A.Offset(0, 4).Value

Comment: FINDval = A.Offset(0, 4).Value

Comment: FINDval = A.Offset(0, 4).Value is the error point. The entire code is highlighted in this line.

Comment: Retry the code, now without the Findval function which didn t work for you (no clue why)